# Should I place air holes in my custom MacBook Pro case?

Tags: macbook-pro, case

I'm fabricating a plexiglass case just like [this](https://sc01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1j0yoHFXXXXcnaXXXq6xXFXXX5/A4-size-acrylic-brochure-holders.jpg) to snugly fit my new MacBook Pro. I'll slide the laptop inside whenever I'm traveling for safety reasons.

It'll only be accessible from the right side. Should I place air holes in the back if it's going to be on whilst the lid is closed?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you definitely do not want to block any vents - no matter if the lid is closed or not.

You can read Apple's instructions on not blocking vents here:

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202179

Note that there are vents both along the side and on the back of the MacBook Pro. Don't block any of them.